# Using sed to replace all stdout from within .bashrc

Tags: sed, bash

I want to conduct a sed operation on all output in my bash shell. Basically I want to put the sed command in .bashrc so it "listens" for certain keywords to do something with them.

For instance I am looking to put something like this in .bashrc:

> sed ''/critical/s//$(printf "CRITICAL")/g''

So that anytime the word "critical" pops up, it is changed to "CRITICAL". This might be when I cat a file, am using vi, or am telnetted into another system. What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: This will have all kinds of odd corner cases, for example: what do you want it to do when you delete a character from "CRITICAL"? And then what if you add it back but capitalized? A fascinating question...

Comment: Also, what is the difference between `sed ''/critical/s//$(printf "CRITICAL")/g''` and `sed s/critical/CRITICAL/g` supposed to be?  (And your quoting there is just a bit odd.)

Answer (score 1):

Doing this from the shell is not going to work at all well, because many commands require direct access to the terminal and/or behave differently if they are not connected directly to the terminal (due to buffering).  Additionally, while you can force redirection to a file (`exec` without a command), you can't redirect down a pipe.

The correct way to do this is probably to use something like the `exec` mechanism in `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

`expect` can do this during `interact` "mode". Details in [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565920902).